# Erro com promise fetch

Tags: javascript, api, promises

Pessoal estou fazendo um projeto de iniciante com API,mas chega em uma parte que eu defino uma função mas de alguma forma da erro :

```
script.js:29 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
    at criar (script.js:29)
    at script.js:10
```

o codigo completo :

```
let cont = document.querySelector(".sea");

function gerar (id , num ) {
    fetch(`http://api.football-data.org/v2/players/${id}/matches` , {
    "headers":  {
        "X-Auth-Token":"dc27d36b147a479bae295e494c925263"

    }
}).then( r => r.json()).then(r => criar(r,num));

}


function jogadores() {
    
    let primeiro = Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
    let segundo  = Math.round(Math.random() * 50)
    
    gerar (primeiro,1);
    gerar (segundo,2);
    
}



function criar(r,num) {

    let play = cont.document.querySelector(`.box${num}`)


        
}

jogadores()
```

Comment: tira o `cont.` do `cont.document.querySelector('.box${num}')`

Comment: esse cont. faz referencia ao sea que é o conteiner de duas divs que irei selecionar ...

Answer (score 0):

Sua variável `cont` já é um elemento, então você não precisa do `.document`.

Você pode usar o `.querySelector` direto na variável cont:

```
let play = cont.querySelector(`.box${num}`)
```